# При скачивания видео из Youtube с помощью pytube и tkinter произойдёт ошибка. Почему?

Tags: python, tkinter, youtube, pytube

Я создал графическую программу которая должен скачать видео из ютуб. Программа откроется но при нажатии на кнопку скачать выйдет такая ошибка:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Savetube\Savetube.py", line 28, in download
    yt = pytube.YouTube(link)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 71, in __init__
    self.video_id = extract.video_id(url)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pytube\extract.py", line 162, in video_id
    return regex_search(r"(?:v=|\/)([0-9A-Za-z_-]{11}).*", url, group=1)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pytube\helpers.py", line 127, in regex_search
    results = regex.search(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Не знаю почему.
Вот код программа:

```
from tkinter import
import pytube

root=Tk()
root.geometry('700x500')
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
root.title("Save video from Youtube")


def func():
    root=Toplevel()
    root.title('Hello')
    root.geometry('300x200')


try:
    def main():
        global link, place
        lab=Label(root, text='Добавьте адрес для скачивания: ', font='Times 24')
        lab.grid(row=1, column=3)
        link=Entry(root, width=50, bd=3)
        link.grid(row=2, column=3)
    
        labe=Label(root, text='Выберите место для сохранения: ', font='Times 24')
        labe.grid(row=3, column=3)
        place=Entry(root, width=50, bd=3)
        place.grid(row=4, column=3)
    
    
        def download():
            yt = pytube.YouTube(link)
            stream = yt.streams.first()
            stream.download(place)
    
    
    
        download=Button(root, text="Скачать", width=10, height=3, command=download, 
        bg='green', fg='black')
        download.grid(row=4, column=4)
except:
    exlab=Label(root, text='Извините произошла ошибка', font='Times 24')
    exlab.grid(row=6, column=3)


main()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Какая ошибка то?

Comment: Блок try... except... не правильно используете.

Comment: Без них тоже выйдет ошибка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Entry** не может быть строкой, по этому нужно использовать `Entry.get()` в твоем случае это: `link.get()`, `place.get()` то есть:

```
def download():
        yt = pytube.YouTube(link.get())
        stream = yt.streams.first()
        stream.download(place.get())
```